# Elixir + Phoenix on Heroku : Timeout error after 15 seconds

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

**Context:** I'm running a elixir+phoenix app https://github.com/endeepak/stub_on_web on Heroku. I've followed steps mentioned in http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku for deploying the app.

**Problem:** When a POST request takes longer than 15 seconds, the web server returns 500 Internal server error with logs showing error as `no case clause matching: {:error, :timeout}`. Error stack is pasted below

```
2015-11-10T16:56:06.680425+00:00 app[web.1]: 16:56:06.680 request_id=19c1ba3f-cfaf-476f-a145-12d234b61c55 [info] POST /stub_urls
2015-11-10T16:56:21.684018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/stub_urls" host=stubonweb.herokuapp.com request_id=19c1ba3f-cfaf-476f-a145-12d234b61c55 fwd="43.247.159.40" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15004ms status=500 bytes=243
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683882+00:00 app[web.1]: 16:56:21.683 [error] #PID<0.429.0> running StubOnWeb.Endpoint terminated
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683887+00:00 app[web.1]: Server: stubonweb.herokuapp.com:80 (http)
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683888+00:00 app[web.1]: Request: POST /stub_urls
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683889+00:00 app[web.1]: ** (exit) an exception was raised:
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683890+00:00 app[web.1]:     ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {:error, :timeout}
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683891+00:00 app[web.1]:         (plug) lib/plug/parsers/urlencoded.ex:10: Plug.Parsers.URLENCODED.parse/5
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683892+00:00 app[web.1]:         (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:186: Plug.Parsers.reduce/6
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683893+00:00 app[web.1]:         (stub_on_web) lib/stub_on_web/endpoint.ex:1: StubOnWeb.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683894+00:00 app[web.1]:         (stub_on_web) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: StubOnWeb.Endpoint.call/2
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683894+00:00 app[web.1]:         (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
2015-11-10T16:56:21.683895+00:00 app[web.1]:         (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

My observations

- It is not the Heroku router's "H12 error" which happens if request takes longer that 30s. Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout . I couldn't get much help from heroku support as it seems like web server issue and they don't know erlang/elixir.
- I've tried running on local with production config, simulated a delay of 60s. The request returns 200 OK response after 60s without any timeout error as above.

Is there any configuration I'm missing here? Any other thoughts?

Comment: This github issue might be related: https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/833

Comment: Thanks @PatrickOscity. That issue led me to another thread in phoenix issues and a temporary fix for the problem.

If anyone else is facing similar issue, please refer https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/459#issuecomment-155657741 for explanation and a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happened since I had added a plug to read request body and save it as private assigns in conn for future access. The code used earlier was

```
defp copy_req_body(conn, _) do
    {:ok, body, _} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn, length: 1_000_000_000)
    Plug.Conn.put_private(conn, :raw_request_body, body)
end

plug :copy_req_body

plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison
```

There seems to an issue with plug which causes :timeout when the Plug.Parsers try to read the body again.

The temp work around for now is to use code as suggested in https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/459#issuecomment-155671415

Reference commit: https://github.com/endeepak/stub_on_web/commit/47192558f501652edd8cd237a5a2430f38177ca4